# Sharing data conflicts between two View Controller using UIApplicationDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to share data from a "SampleAppdelegate" to two view controller "ContactViewController.m" and "DrinksViewController.m".

In SampleAppdelegate:

```
@interface SampleAppdelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate , UINavigationBarDelegate>
```

So I've included below code in respective view controller.

In ContactViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad   
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    SampleAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
    contactDatabaseObject = (ContactDatabaseObject *)[appDelegate.contactDetails objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSLog(@"%@", contactDatabaseObject.contactName);  
    [appDelegate release];  
}
```

In DrinksViewController.m

```
(void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    SampleAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
    drinksDatabaseObject = (DrinksDatabaseObject *)[appDelegate.drinkDetails objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSLog(@"%@", drinksDatabaseObject.drinkName);  
    [appDelegate release];  
}
```

The problem is "sharing application delegate is is both of the code not working at the same time. ( that is, if I comment above in a view controller then other is working fine as as expected).

Actually i'm using a ***tab-bar*** with two item as above viewControllers. So loading of the first controller happens fine. But when i click the second view controller the iphone-simulator is terminated with any warning. ( And at the same time the code works normal if I comment it in any one of the view controller).  Please help me to resolve above issues or suggest a method to accomplish above feature.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

You're not owner of `appDelegate`, no need to release it.

P.S. If you're asking for help and writing something about warning, you should always copy warning here to shed more light on your problem.

Comment: P.S.S. You should also check for number of objects in your drinkDetails array. If it will be empty, objectAtIndex:0 will throw an exception.

Comment: P.S.S.S. If you're confident enough to hard code 0, you might as well just call `lastObject` on NSArray. It won't throw an exception, it'll just return nil.

Comment: yes, now it is working. Thanks for answering and spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be releasing the appDelegate.